# xcopy only working if I use /F to display full filenames

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy, copy

I was initially just using `copy` but I got this output:

```
C:\repos\AutomatedBuildTesting (master -> origin)
(2020-09-18  8:49:01.12) λ copy ".hooks/*" ".git/hooks/*"
commit-msg
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

So I tried `xcopy` and after trying a few things eventually discovered it will only copy if I include the `F` flag to display full file names.  Can anyone explain this?

```
C:\repos\AutomatedBuildTesting (master -> origin)
(2020-09-18  8:48:32.95) λ xcopy ".hooks/*" ".git/hooks/*"
0 File(s) copied

C:\repos\AutomatedBuildTesting (master -> origin)
(2020-09-18  8:48:58.07) λ xcopy ".hooks/*" ".git/hooks/*" /F
Overwrite C:\repos\AutomatedBuildTesting\.git\hooks\commit-msg (Yes/No/All)? y
C:\repos\AutomatedBuildTesting\.hooks\commit-msg -> C:\repos\AutomatedBuildTesting\.git\hooks\commit-msg
1 File(s) copied
```

Comment: cmd paths are written with \ not /. / are flags. what if you write the paths with a \?

Comment: That fixed it, which seems interesting to me. Why does it work with the `/F` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write your paths with `/` instead of `\`. If you change them to `\` it should work. I can't tell you exactly why this is that it works with /f and not without, but I know from experience that with paths written as `/` instead of `\` its treated differently.

I'm assuming that when a parameter is included, cmd is able to work out that `/` is part of a path, not a parameter, and as such treats the command correctly.